# In C#, if I am returning a Point and cannot find the coordinate what should I return?

Tags: c#

Firstly it is not an exception since it is part of the normal flow of operations.  I tried to return a null object but this was not allowed.  I can get by returning a Point with negative coordinates but it feels like a hack.  For example if I return (-1, -1) then instead of checking for a negative number, conceivably some use of my library might directly check for equality with -1 which will then break if my internal implementation changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could return a nullable Point by changing your return type to `Point?`. That way you can also return `null`.

Otherwise you can create a static Point instance somewhere with (−1, −1) and always compare against that. `PointUtils.InvalidPoint` is probably nicer to read than `p.x == -1 && p.y == -1`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I should be long sleeping, actually ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the function's return type to `Point?`, then return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

How about Point.Empty? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.empty%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: Well, that's just (0, 0) which *might* be a valid result, considering that the OP contemplated about negative member values.

Comment: Fair enough. If so, a nullable Point is the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't bite you afterwards (i.e. if your points cannot be 0,0): Point.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the method to take an `out bool isValid` parameter.  If isValid is false, the user would know to ignore the Point result.

Comment: In those cases I usually do it the other way around and make the actual resulting value the `out` parameter so that the method result always specifies success or not. Just like `Integer.TryParse` does.